# Does the following Diophantine equation have nontrivial rational solutions?

Tags: elliptic-curves, diophantine-equations, nt.number-theory

Are there any solutions to the equation $s^{2}(1+t^{2})^{2}+t^{2}(1+s^{2})^{2}=u^2$ where $s,t,u\in \mathbb{Q}$ and $0 < s,t<1$?  If so, is there a simple way to parametrize them all?

If I am understanding the geometry behind this problem, even if we pick a specific value for $t$ we are left with an elliptic curve, and it is possible there could be infinitely many solutions.

This question arises from some related (and somewhat esoteric) questions I have about rational points on unit circles.  But this question looked "pretty" enough, I thought I'd ask the experts here.

Comment: I don't know about parametrising them all, but if I got my calculations right then setting t=1/2 gives an elliptic curve of rank 1 and I see plenty of points. For example (all with t=1/2) s=15/16 or 14911/369120.

Comment: Random specialisations of $t$ all seem to have rank at least 1, so probably the curve in $s$ and $u$ has rank 1 over $\mathbf{Q}(t)$ which means there will be, amongst other solutions, infinitely many parametric solutions in $s$ and $t$. 

Comment: naively trying some maple computations give: if
$$
z^5+(h^2-1)z^4+2z^3+(2h^2-2)z^2+(1+4h^2)z+h^2-1=0
$$
is a rational solution $z$ for given rational $h$
then
$$
t=z, s = 2h/(1+t^2)
$$
is a rational solution.  I used a special case of the trivial parametrization
$$
(2h)/(1+h^2))^2 +((1-h^2)/(1+h^2))^2 =1
$$



Comment: As Kevin Buzzard indicated, now the $(s,u)$ curve is isomorphic to
$$y^2=x^3+(-2t^4-8t^2-2)x^2+(t^8+8t^6+14t^4+8t^2+1)x,$$
and a point on this is $(4t^2,2t^5-2t)$, not being torsion.
Mapping back to your $(s,u)$, this is
$$s={t^4-1\over 4t^2},u={t^8+8t^6-2t^4+8t^2+1\over 16t^3}.$$
There is also
$$s={t-1\over t+1},u={(t^2+1)^2\over(t+1)^2},$$
deriving from $(x,y)=(t^4+2t^3+2t^2+2t+1,2t^5-2t)$.
Further, Modulo primes like 11 and 19, along with the torsion results $x=0,(t^2+1)^2,t^4+6t^2+1$, these are the only $F_p$ solutions with degree bounded by 4, and so are the only rational ones there.


Comment: These are a very useful start.  Junkie, how did you find that isomorphism?  The only method I know of to pass from y^2=quartic to y^2=cubic does not preserve rationality.

Follow-up question: is it possible to prove that this is the full set of points over Q(t)?  Under specializations of t?

Comment: There is a short GP package (based on a paper done by Mike Artin, Fernando Rodriguez-Villegas and John Tate) to pass from y^2=quartic to y^2=cubic (although some of this was done in an old paper by Hermite much before, I can post the reference if needed). Check the link http://www.ma.utexas.edu/cnt/cnt-frames.html (the file jacobians)

Comment: If $u^2=quartic(s)$ and we know a point, here $(0,t)$, you can follow Cassels 8(iii) in *Lectures on Elliptic Curves*, or computer algebra systems will do it, to get the rational isomorphism. I suspect we can show that the Mordell-Weil group over $Q(t)$ is only $(Z/2)^2\oplus Z$ by descent or cohomology, but the details maybe tricky, especially if by hand. Another approach, is noting the rank 1 specializations and use Silverman's theorem, III.11 in his *Advanced Topics in the Arithmetic of Elliptic Curves*, effectively. Finally, Rank *increase* upon specialization is difficult, generally.


Comment: Dividing the original equation by $t^2$, and rescaling $U$ we are left with an equation of the form $U^{2}=S^{4}-2dS^{2}+1$.  Then setting $x=-d+(U+1)/S^{2}$ and $y=x/S$ (when $S\neq 0$, $d\neq \pm 1$), we have the elliptic curve $2y^{2}=x^{3}+2dx^{2}+(d^{2}-1)x$.  When $(x,y)$ is not a 2-torsion point, or the point at infinity, we can go back via $S=x/y$, $U=(x+d)S^{2}-1$.  It isn't difficult to match up the 2-torsion correctly, and this gives us the rational isomorphism we need.  (Following up with more changes in coordinates as necessary.)

Comment: @junkie: When citing the theorem from Silverman, did you mean Theorem III.11.1?  Also, do you know of a citation where the theorem is made effective?  I'm having trouble trying to apply it to this situation.

As for rank increase, you say it is difficult, but that seems to imply that in certain cases it is possible to analyze what happens.  What are some methods you know of?  Is it easier if we assume some highly believed conjectures?

Comment: The Theorem is 11.4 (the whole section is related). I don't know if/where an effective statement about Silverman's specialization is made. I was almost tempted to make a question here (MO) about it. As for rank increase, the only guess I know, is that for 100% (density) of the curves the rank is as "small as possible", that is either the rank over $Q(t)$, or 1 more when the root number switches.


Answer (score 7, accepted):

(*Edited with more details.*)

I know this is a *really* old question, but this has a nice connection to a problem considered by Euler, what is now known as *Euler bricks*, and I couldn't resist. The OP's equation is equivalent to finding three rationals $a,b,c$ such that,

$$\begin{aligned}
a^2+b^2\; &= u_1^2\\
a^2-c^2\; &= u_2^2\\
b^2-c^2\; &= u_3^2
\end{aligned}\tag1$$

A solution (essentially by Euler) is,

$$a = \frac{s^2+1}{2s},\quad b = \frac{t^2+1}{2t},\quad c = 1\tag2$$

where $s,t$ must satisfy,

$$s^2(t^2+1)^2+t^2(s^2+1)^2 = w^2\tag3$$

and is the equation considered by the OP. For ***any*** solution to $(1)$ with $c\neq0$, then $s,t$ can be recovered as,

$$s = \frac{a\pm\sqrt{a^2-c^2}}{c} = \frac{a\pm u_2}{c}$$

$$t = \frac{b\pm\sqrt{b^2-c^2}}{c} = \frac{b\pm u_3}{c}$$

A small solution to $(3)$ is,

$$s = \frac{4p}{p^2-1},\quad t = \frac{3p^2+1}{p(p^2+3)}\tag4$$

This is the essentially the same one given by Euler for *[Euler bricks](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/EulerBrick.html)*,

$$\begin{aligned}
\alpha^2+\beta^2\; &= v_1^2\\
\alpha^2+\gamma^2\; &= v_2^2\\
\beta^2+\gamma^2\; &= v_3^2
\end{aligned}$$

where we have used $p \to p\sqrt{-1}$, and have correspondingly tweaked $(1)-(4)$. From this initial rational point $(4)$, one can then generate an infinite more.